# I have a problem creating a VBA to dynamically add data to my table in ms-access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have created a form in MS Access and have created a button (`cmdAdd`) to add the filled fields in a table (`tbCadastro`) dynamically.

See SQL statements below:

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Add data
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbCadastro(Requisição, Cliente, CPF_CNPJ, ID_Cartao, ValorDisponivelCartao, Tarifa, ValorBrutoDevolucao, ValorLiquido, Motivo, Observacoes, DataPagamento, FormaPagamento, BancoCredito, AgenciaCredito, ContaCredito, BancoDebito, AgenciaDebito, ContaDebito)" & _
            " VALUES (" & Me.txtCliente & ",'" & Me.txtID_Cartao & "','" & Me.txtCPF_CNPJ & "','" & Me.txtValorDisponivelCartao & "','" & _
            Me.txtTarifa & "','" & Me.txtValorBrutoDevolucao & "','" & Me.txtValorLiquido & "','" & Me.txtMotivo & "','" & Me.txtObservacoes & "','" & _
            Me.txtDataPagamento & "','" & Me.txtAgenciaCredito & "','" & Me.txtContaCredito & "','" & Me.cboBancoCredito & "','" & Me.BancoDebito & "','" & _
            Me.AgenciaDebito & "','" & Me.ContaDebito & "','" & Me.cboFormaPagamento & "','" & Me.cboRequisicao & "')"

    'Refresh form
    FrmCadastro.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

My problem is this:

When I click on the Add button (after filling in the fields) it generates the error:

> Error in the execution progress 438: The object does not accept this property or method.

We have already reviewed all fields in the form's design mode, renaming and differentiating the fields from the labels.

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Thank you all.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print`: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: @Andre I'm sorry for the ignorance, I'm new to this. How do I debug and see where the error is? Is it your own module where it is written or code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the SQL statement. If any fields are number type, remove apostrophes; if any are date/time type, use # delimiter. Exactly which line throws error - is it the Requery? Try removing the `.Form` part - try just `Me.Requery`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of your error is likely to be this line:

```vb
FrmCadastro.Form.Requery
```

Here you are accessing the object returned by the [Form **property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.form) of your [Form **object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form). This property is typically used to access the form element of a subform so as to access the fields within the subform.

Whilst the [Requery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.requery) method is applicable to the main [Form object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form), it is not a method of the object returned by the [Form property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.form) of the [Form object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form), thus resulting in the error you have witnessed:

> Error in the execution progress 438: The object does not accept this property or method.

That is, the `Form` object obtained via the `Form` property does not accept the `Requery` method.

---

Assuming that `FrmCadastro` is the form on which the button `cmdAdd` resides, then to requery the form's record source, you should be able to use:

```vb
Me.Requery
```

---

I would also suggest using parameters in place of concatenating the values in your SQL statement, as this avoids the need to handle varying data types, and also prevents SQL injection.

For example:

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO tbCadastro "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    Requisição, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    Cliente,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    CPF_CNPJ, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ID_Cartao, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ValorDisponivelCartao,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    Tarifa,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ValorBrutoDevolucao,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ValorLiquido,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    Motivo,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    Observacoes,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    DataPagamento,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    FormaPagamento,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    BancoCredito,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    AgenciaCredito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ContaCredito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    BancoDebito,  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    AgenciaDebito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    ContaDebito "
    strSQL = strSQL & ") "
    strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtcliente, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtID_Cartao, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtCPF_CNPJ, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtValorDisponivelCartao, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtTarifa, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtValorBrutoDevolucao, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtValorLiquido, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtMotivo, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtObservacoes, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtDataPagamento, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtAgenciaCredito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @txtContaCredito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @cboBancoCredito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @BancoDebito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @AgenciaDebito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @ContaDebito, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @cboFormaPagamento, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    @cboRequisicao "
    strSQL = strSQL & ") "

    With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
        .Parameters("@txtcliente") = Me.txtCliente
        .Parameters("@txtID_Cartao") = Me.txtID_Cartao
        .Parameters("@txtCPF_CNPJ") = Me.txtCPF_CNPJ
        .Parameters("@txtValorDisponivelCartao") = Me.txtValorDisponivelCartao
        .Parameters("@txtTarifa") = Me.txtTarifa
        .Parameters("@txtValorBrutoDevolucao") = Me.txtValorBrutoDevolucao
        .Parameters("@txtValorLiquido") = Me.txtValorLiquido
        .Parameters("@txtMotivo") = Me.txtMotivo
        .Parameters("@txtObservacoes") = Me.txtObservacoes
        .Parameters("@txtDataPagamento") = Me.txtDataPagamento
        .Parameters("@txtAgenciaCredito") = Me.txtAgenciaCredito
        .Parameters("@txtContaCredito") = Me.txtContaCredito
        .Parameters("@cboBancoCredito") = Me.cboBancoCredito
        .Parameters("@BancoDebito") = Me.BancoDebito
        .Parameters("@AgenciaDebito") = Me.AgenciaDebito
        .Parameters("@ContaDebito") = Me.ContaDebito
        .Parameters("@cboFormaPagamento") = Me.cboFormaPagamento
        .Parameters("@cboRequisicao") = Me.cboRequisicao
        .Execute dbFailOnError
    End With

    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-echo @LeeMac's answer, simply qualify your Form object in `.Requery` call

```vb
Forms!FrmCadastro.Form.Requery
```

And use a stored query pointing to exact form controls to avoid concatenation or punctuation:

**SQL** *(check mapping of values and columns as names appear out of order)*

```sql
INSERT INTO tbCadastro(Requisição, Cliente, CPF_CNPJ, ID_Cartao, ValorDisponivelCartao, 
                       Tarifa, ValorBrutoDevolucao, ValorLiquido, Motivo, Observacoes, 
                       DataPagamento, FormaPagamento, BancoCredito, AgenciaCredito, 
                       ContaCredito, BancoDebito, AgenciaDebito, ContaDebito)
VALUES (Forms!FrmCadastro!txtCliente, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtID_Cartao, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!txtCPF_CNPJ, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtValorDisponivelCartao, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!txtTarifa, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtValorBrutoDevolucao, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!txtValorLiquido, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtMotivo, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!txtObservacoes, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtDataPagamento, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!txtAgenciaCredito, Forms!FrmCadastro!txtContaCredito, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!cboBancoCredito, Forms!FrmCadastro!BancoDebito, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!AgenciaDebito, Forms!FrmCadastro!ContaDebito, 
        Forms!FrmCadastro!cboFormaPagamento, Forms!FrmCadastro!cboRequisicao)
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Add data
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"

    'Refresh form
    Forms!FrmCadastro.Form.Requery        ' ABSOLUTE REFERENCE
    Me.FrmCadastro.Form.Requery           ' RELATIVE REFERENCE
End Sub
```